# Relaying optional arguments in a wrapper for a variadic function

Tags: c, variadic

I've just discovered variadic functions in C and have defined one as a general notification typedef, that as well as a pointer to a text string can optionally have whatever arguments sent along with it- useful as a generic debug function for instance where I want all the output string manipulation in one place.

Since I want my C files to be as generic as possible I have static variables that contain pointers to possible callbacks in higher code, populated in an init call. Since the pointers may be null if higher code isn't interested, I'd normally have a local wrapper that only calls through the pointer if it's not null. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to forward this fuzzy thing represented by '...' and simply calling the function with '...' in the argument list gives a syntax error.

Is there any way to do this, or am I stuck with having a dummy local handler and having init set null callbacks to a pointer to that?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean. Could you provide an example or two?

Comment: Take debug as an example; most are single text, `DebugMessage("whatever specific error")` but with some you might like to add extra information- the most trivial being the values of some simple variables. Now you COULD use printf and allocate a string buffer, populate it and send it back, but that's more of a pain than `DebugMessage("Failure at test point %d; var1=%d, var2=%d", 23, a, b)` and since DebugMessage is likely to do different things on an embedded platform (output to serial) than on a GUI based desktop PC (pop up a dialog box) you want it up in higher levels. Clearer?

Comment: Partially, yes. You can happily create a variadic function for this. But always remember to provide one version which takes a `va_list` and which is called by the others. There are libraries out there where the authors "forgot" them, and extending them is a real PITA.

Comment: Yeah, figured that'd be the way to go since you need that function anyway in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass on the variadic arguments. You have to fetch them into a `va_list` and pass this to the inner function.

Take a look at [this Question at the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/varargs/vprintf.html). It defines a variadic `error` function that wants to forward to `printf`. This is just your use case.

In the [same FAQs](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html), it is generally recommended to have a version taking `va_list` for every (or most) variadic functions